# Making element rotate to mouse position, after another rotation

Tags: javascript, html, trigonometry

I'm trying to make a tank-simulator of sorts. It's strictly on divs, not on canvas etc. It's already rotating and moving forward/backward how I want it to, but rotating the turret is a bit problematic. I got to the point where the turret rotates to the mouse pointer, however when the tank body rotates, the turret rotation doesn't take it into account (it rotates with the tanks body). Does anyone have any idea how to make it work so that the turret ALWAYS points to the mouse cursor?

Preferably in pure JS.

It's a bit too big to paste, so I'll just link to fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/9pom714a/

Sample of mousemove handler:

```
window.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    mouseX = e.clientX - field.offsetLeft;
    mouseY = e.clientY - field.offsetTop;

    turretAngle = Math.atan2(mouseX - turretBaseX, -(mouseY - turretBaseY)) * (180/Math.PI);

    turretBase.style.transform = 'rotate(' + turretAngle + 'deg)';
})
```

I know the code is a mess, I'll refactor it after I get everything to work ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

substract the tankAngle to the turretAngle rotation like this:

```
window.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    mouseX = e.clientX - field.offsetLeft;
    mouseY = e.clientY - field.offsetTop;

    turretAngle = Math.atan2(mouseX - turretBaseX, -(mouseY - turretBaseY)) * (180/Math.PI);
        turretAngle -= tankAngle;
    turretBase.style.transform = 'rotate(' + turretAngle + 'deg)';

})
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9pom714a/1/